# Inspector failed : port already in use for Javascript webdriverio automation project

Tags: visual-studio, npm, visual-studio-debugging, webdriver-io

I am getting this below error message in Visual studio code

> Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:5859/325cc0fe-d885-4684-a4bf-03ec52ffd060 For help see  https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector 
>   Starting inspector on 127.0.0.1:5859 failed: address already in use 
>   Starting inspector on 127.0.0.1:5859 failed: address already in use

I was trying to add a launch.json debugger option and since it did not work. I deleted the same as well. But the node process is still locked somewhere.

I cant see any process in "ps" command or in "netstat" command. But everytime when I run the project using "npm run xxxx" command, I am getting the above message. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get rid of this issue by manually commenting the --inspect option added to the debugger.